# PHP XMLWriter custom 'doctype'

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

How do I replicate the following with `PHP` `XMLWriter();`

```
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
```

I tried doing the following but could replicate the second ? at the end.

```
$writer->startElement("?qbxml");  
   $writer->writeAttribute('version', '12.0');
```

Comment: If it starts with a `?`, its [a PI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction), not an element.

Comment: Oh okay, so how would I create this line in XML using XMLWriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-pi.php):

```
$writer->writePI("qbxml", 'version="12.0"');
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it go on its own line because when I check the ouput the next element is on the same line as the PI :
`<?qbxml version="12.0"?><QBXML>`

Comment: I imagine that inserting a text node with a value of `\n` will do that. There may also be formatting options.